firebase_auth/channel-error "dev.flutter.pigeon.firebase_auth_platform_interface.FirebaseAuthHostApi.signInWithCredential"
Future LoginOTPVerify(BuildContext context) async {
final otpCode = otpControler.LoginOTPController.text.trim();
if (otpCode.isEmpty) {
  SnackbarHelper()
      .showCustomSnackbar(context, "Please enter your OTP code");
  return;
} else {
  try {
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
      verificationId: verificationId.value,
      smsCode: otpCode,
    ); // Sign in with the credential
    await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    SnackbarHelper().showCustomSnackbar(context, "Sign-in successful!");
    Get.toNamed('/BottomNavigationBar');
  } catch (e) {
    print('this is your error $e');
    SnackbarHelper()
        .showCustomSnackbar(context, "Invalid OTP. Please try again");
  }
}

}

Try below steps:

Enable Keychain Sharing for iOS: Go to Signing & Capabilities in Xcode > Add "Keychain Sharing" capability. This is required for Firebase Authentication on iOS starting with Firebase iOS SDK 9.6.0.

Make sure your GoogleService-Info.plist is correctly placed in the iOS project and matches your Firebase project settings.

Make sure firebase_auth and firebase_core are up-to-date. Run flutter pub upgrade.

Run flutter clean, then flutter run to rebuild the app with correct configurations.



This is for android only for now not for IOS. @Tech Ramakant

@ZohethGeorge Please check once this GitHub Issue https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/13065#issuecomment-2225372083, The discussion highlights similar kind of error
